# USB ubuntu - how to retrieve saved data after reboot

Tags: live-usb, data-recovery

I saved couple of important files from my windows computer to USB Ubuntu while Ubuntu was running. But on restarting the USB Ubuntu I am unable to locate those files. is it normal that it  is erased? or is there any way i have get it back? I created a .New folder within documents and placed the files in that folder. but once i shut down Ubuntu and opened again those files are nowhere.. please help

Answer (score 1):

Any changes made after booting with an Ubuntu live USB (including files/folders created) are usually erased when you shutdown, unless you made the live USB **persistent** when you created it.  That means that a file is created on the USB where the changes are stored.  Persistence is usually not done by default - only if you request it when you create the USB.

If you want to make the USB persistent then you'll need to create it again from scratch and make a persistent file.  I believe PenDriveLinux's program and Ubuntu's own live USB creator can make it persistent.

(technically, I don't think the files are actually **wiped** when you shut down - I believe they only exist in RAM and aren't copied to the USB)

Comment: The smallest USB drive to make a Ubuntu Live USB is 1GB. The persistent live USB needs a bigger USB drive.